# Class Dependency for JARS - Java

Tags: java, reflection, graph, jar, dependencies

I was wondering if there is a Java library that can detect dependecies between classes located in JAR files and plot them into a graph at run-time. Could you please inform me of such existing tools?

```
e.g. Owner -> Address -> Street 
                      -> Region   
           -> Bank Account
           -> Name
```

Thank you.

Comment: This question is off-topic as it asks for a software recommendation. Please visit the [help] and also read [ask] for details.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [JarAnalyzer](http://www.kirkk.com/main/Main/JarAnalyzer) ... It's primary purpose is to traverse through a directory, parse each of the jar files in that directory, and identify the dependencies between the jar files.

Comment: Thank you. I am interested in solving mostly dependencies between classes.